# With aiohttp.post how do I pass it some data to iterate

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

According to the documentation [on aiohttp here](http://pythonhosted.org/aiohttp/client.html#streaming-uploads):  I can specify a coroutine to feed data, but when I run it (code example below) it tells me *TypeError: Only io.IOBase, multidict and (name, file) pairs allowed*

I've tried several other ways to accomplish this but keep running into trouble.

What I'm trying to achieve is that I can read from a named pipe (this will have streaming audio data continuously coming in). And then I want to forward that immediately streamingly to a Speech To Text API (Watson in this case).

My additional requirement (important one) is that I cannot block on reading the file, because if I do the writing side of that name pipe (think unix socket), will block that program and degrade the sound.

What works is just straight on passing the file handle to the async http request, but then I don't get the opportunity to check and interrupt the data. How do I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import aiohttp
import io

FILENAME = 'poem.txt'

my_buffer = io.BytesIO()
queue = asyncio.Queue()

with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as fd:
    while True:
        chunk = fd.read(50)
        # do some processing on chunk (read audio level)
        if (chunk):
            asyncio.ensure_future(queue.put(chunk))
        else:
            print("we're out of the original file")
            my_buffer.write(b'')
            break

@asyncio.coroutine
def stream_coroutine():

    print("read chunk")
    chunk = yield from queue.get()

    if (chunk == b''):
        print("chunks out!!")
        return

    yield chunk


async def getPage():
    print("queue len", queue.qsize())
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('http://requestb.in/zq456szq', data=stream_coroutine) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(getPage())
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, where is `while` loop in `stream_coroutine()`?
Why do you read only once?

Also a coroutine should be called: `data=stream_coroutine()` not `data=stream_coroutine`